# ngModelChange is not firing

Tags: angular5

hello what could be the problem ngModelChange is not firing here?

```
<input hidden [(ngModel)]="Monday" type="checkbox" name="monday" id="monday" value="monday" (ngModelChange)="changed()">

<label class="btn btn-event-repeat" (click)="Monday = !Monday">
     <span class="daylongname">Monday</span>
     <span class="dayshortname">Mon</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Try this:

(click)="changed($event)"

or

(change)="changed($event)"

Comment: @A.Sakkeer can't do that since i'm not gonna manipulate through component function just in view so final would be in ngModelChange="Tuesday = false; Wednesday = false; etc etc" and i want ngModelChange to trigger